# How to store and retrieve username and password in webservice

Tags: android, soap

I am new to android. How to pass,store and retrieve username and password form web-service. i built my web-service in soap.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.confirm);

        ipaddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_Mail_ID);
        userid    = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_uname);
        password  =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_psw);
        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Confirm);
        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            //  if (UserName.trim().length() > 0 && Password.trim().length() > 0) {
            // (UserName.equals("userid")&& Password.equals("password")) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Confirm.this, select_company.class);

                Urltag.UrlTag = "LoginAuthentication";
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                String UserName = userid.getText().toString();   
                b.putString("UserName", UserName);

                String Password = password.getText().toString();
                b.putString("Password", Password);
                intent.putExtras(b);


                if((userid.getText().toString()).equals(password.getText().toString())){
                Toast.makeText(Confirm.this, "Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                startActivity(intent);

                finish();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(Confirm.this, "Please check username and password !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            }enter code here
```

Comment: what are you asking??

Comment: pls give me suggetion..

Comment: i asking......when we are login than that username and password store in webservice

Comment: and after logout ..  reusing that username and pass for again login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to login to the application using a web service, you need to do following things

- write a method to pass the username and the passwords as a parameter to your web service
- then in your `onclick` method, take the username and the password from `EditText`
- and just call your implemented method by giving your username and the password

you can use `AsyncTask` to do this.

Below is some codes which you can have some idea about this

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(JSONObject parm,String url) throws JSONException {

         InputStream is = null;
         JSONObject jObj = null;
         String json = "";
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            /*JSONObject parm = new JSONObject();
            parm.put("agencyId", 27);
            parm.put("caregiverPersonId", 47);*/

        /*  if(!(jObj.isNull("d"))){
                jObj=null;
            }
            */

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            HttpEntity body = new StringEntity(parm.toString(), "utf8");
            httpPost.setEntity(body);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            is = httpEntity.getContent();          

               /* String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                Log.w("myApp", response);*/

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

     //   JSONObject jObj2 = new JSONObject(json);
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
             jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
```

above method is passing any parameter to a desired web service and return the result of the web service as a `JsonObject`. you have to give your parameters and also the web service url.

this is a method to check the login

```
public JSONObject AuthenticateUser(final String user,final String pass){

    // boolean status = false;
     /*String authenticate = null;
     String returnValue=null;*/
    // String  authenticatePersonID=null;
     JSONObject authenticate1=new JSONObject() ;

     JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

          try {
               JsonParser jpar = new JsonParser();
               JSONObject userParam = new JSONObject();
               userParam.put("username", user);
               userParam.put("password", pass);
               json = jpar.getJSONFromUrl(userParam,URL);                                           
               authenticate1 = json.getJSONObject("d");                             

              } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

          }    

    return authenticate1;
}
```

you can just call the following  in your `onclick` method.

```
String username = yourEditTex.getText.tostring; 
String password=yourEditTex.getText.tostring; 
JSONObject authenticate = AuthenticateUser(username,password);
```

[list view code one](http://pastie.org/10196741)

[adapter](http://pastie.org/10196746)

[View](http://pastie.org/10196755)

Comment: and if username and paswword match than go to next activity

Comment: no... that is not the right way of authenticate... if you want that way... you have to do it in the web service..[weather the username and password is same]... just call like this 

String username = yourEditTex.getText.tostring;
String password=  yourEditTex.getText.tostring;
JSONObject authenticate = AuthenticateUser(username,password);

Comment: in my webservice i store username="admin" and password="admin"

Comment: when login activity i will put both username and password.... than its not give any result